# Cannot COPY a CSV file from local machine to remote server

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the below command to import the CSV file which is placed in my local system to a table in remote server.

But i'm getting the below error.

```
NOTICE:  table "temp_table" does not exist, skipping

ERROR:  could not open file "/Users/linu/downloads/numb.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "copy temp_table from '/Users/linu/downloads/numb.csv' with delimiter ';' quote '"' csv "
PL/pgSQL function staging.load_csv_file(text,text,integer) line 22 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 58P01
```

Below is the function details,Can anyone please help me to find  solution for this without copying the file at server side and suggesting necessary changes to the below function to make it work?

I understand that the error is because the server cannot identify my local path,Have gone through few posts but didn't understand on how to resolve it.Any hint or suggestions will be of great help.

```
**Function call**
select staging.load_csv_file('numb','/Users/linu/downloads/numb.csv',73)

**Function Body**
create or replace function staging.load_csv_file
(
    target_table text,
    csv_path text,
    col_count integer
)

returns void as $$

declare

iter integer; -- dummy integer to iterate columns with
col text; -- variable to keep the column name at each iteration
col_first text; -- first column name, e.g., top left corner on a csv file or spreadsheet

begin
    set schema 'staging';

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
    create  table temp_table ();

    -- add just enough number of columns
    for iter in 1..col_count
    loop
        execute format('alter table temp_table add column col_%s text;', iter);
    end loop;

    -- copy the data from csv file
    execute format('copy temp_table from %L with delimiter '';'' quote ''"'' csv ', csv_path);

    iter := 1;
    col_first := (select col_1 from temp_table limit 1);
  -- raise notice 'path', csv_path;
    -- update the column names based on the first row which has the column names
    for col in execute format('select unnest(string_to_array(trim(temp_table::text, ''()''), '','')) from temp_table where col_1 = %L', col_first)
    loop
        execute format('alter table temp_table rename column col_%s to %s', iter, col);
        iter := iter + 1;
    end loop;

    -- delete the columns row
    execute format('delete from temp_table where %s = %L', col_first, col_first);

    -- change the temp table name to the name given as parameter, if not blank
    if length(target_table) > 0 then
        execute format('alter table temp_table rename to %I', target_table);
    end if;

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

Note: I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in PostgreSQL server code, since the database server has no access to files on your client.

You have to write client code in a language of your choice that supports `COPY FROM STDIN`.

Comment: I have copied the file to the server,then also i'm not able to execute the COPY command in my PgAdmin.                              
ERROR:  could not open file "/home/etl/bi/csv_import/numb.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "copy temp_table from '/home/etl/bi/csv_import/numb.csv' with delimiter ';' quote '"' csv "
PL/pgSQL function staging.load_csv_file(text,text,integer) line 22 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 58P01

Comment: Can you please suggest on this,It will be really helpful!

Comment: Well, either the file is not in this place, or the OS user `postgres` lacks the permissions to read it (test with `cat /home/etl/bi/csv_import/numb.csv`).