# Import CSV with unknown columns to PostgreSQL using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm trying to import a CSV file which contains 74 columns to a PostgreSQL table.I have tried to do it via PostgreSQL and couldn't able to do it, below is the post, from this post came to know that i need a client side programming language to accomplish this,So thought of doing it through python as our project uses python for additional backend operations.

I'm new to python and i have searched a lot but in every example i found, the table column names was predefined, in my case since the CSV contains 74 columns it will not be possible to create a table by hardcoding every columns.

**So can anyone suggest or recommend a generalised solution for this,It will be of great help.**

[Cannot COPY a CSV file from local machine to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787570/cannot-copy-a-csv-file-from-local-machine-to-remote-server)

Comment: you are going to get heavily downvoted (not by me) this is not a coding service, state what you have tried and why it does not work

Comment: I understand you want to read the file into a table. So if your CSV file has 74 columns, do you want 74 columns in the table? What data type should they be? If the CSV file has a different number of columns, do you want to create a different table with that number of columns? Or is there something else you want to do?

Comment: @Deepstop Thanks for the response, Yes my CSV contains 74 columns and not necessarily i need 74 columns, mostly 10-15 columns i need.All columns i want is having TEXT datatype,If the CSV is having different number of columns i want to create a table based on that columns.

Comment: @E.Serra Hi Sorry for that, But i'm new to python and couldn't able to catch up with it,Have tried and gone through a lot of solutions, but couldn't able to find a solution with dynamic columns

Comment: Also did try using postgreSQL and i have mentioned what i have don in the link.

Comment: @Deepstop Can you suggest or recommend on how to approach this scenario?

Comment: Check out [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether this is a for production or just casual use, you need to

1. Figure out how many columns there are in the CSV
2. Determine the data types, as CSV doesn't have data types that means
   you will need to examine the columns individually to determine which
   fit your criteria as text. (Alternatively if the data are available
   in Excel format you could use a the openpyxl library to read it and
   it will provide you with some data type information).
3. If you want to actually have a table with a variable number of
   columns then you would need to execute a  `CREATE TABLE` query to do
   so. Depending on the what you will end up doing with the data in your
   application, it might be better to use a general structure where the
   column number is in a field. Let me explain that.

Say your CSV is like this

```
'Hdg 1', 'Hdg 2', 'Hdg 3', 'Hdg 4', 'Hdg 5'
'Some text', 23, 47, 'More text', 'Even more text', 21
'A string', 66, 22, 'Another string', 'Last string', 42
```

For step 1, counting the columns should be straightforward, and the csv reader package  suggested would be of help.

To satisfy 2, you would need to decide which are strings (maybe by the quote character, maybe because it's all digits, maybe it can be determine from the heading, etc.

For #3, let's assume that we use a single table to store our data (rather than creating a custom table for each new import, which I think should be avoided unless absolutely necessary for some reason).

If we take the first data row and extract the text [`Some text`, `More text`, `Even more text`], from columns 1, 4 and 5 respectively we can use any one of the column number, the heading or the position in the list of text string (0, 1 and 2) to identify the original column. If using a single table then you also might need to identify the origin of the data, say if it came from 'employees.csv' then you would use 'employees' as the identifier. So each row of the CSV file would result in the `INSERT` of 3 rows in the new table. I will not show the primary key but there should also be one.

```
'employees', 'Hdg 1', 'Some text'
'employees', 'Hdg 2', 'More text'
'employees', 'Hdg 3', 'Even more text'
```

or

```
'employees', 0, 'Some text'
'employees', 1, 'More text'
'employees', 2, 'Even more text'
```

You could also put the first column in a related table which lists all the data sources. These are all design decisions you will need to make depending on how you want to access the data, volume of data, etc.

If you need to present the data in tabular format then you could write a view that uses the RDBMS' pivot query to retrieve the data that way.